# Python マルチプロセスで同じログファイルにログを書き出すときの注意点はありますか

Tags: python, logging, python-multiprocessing

同一のアプリケーション内で複数のマルチプロセスを立ち上げ、並列性のある動作をさせる必要があります。
しかし、外部から見ると、ひとつのアプリケーションなので、ログはひとつにまとめ時系列に記述さえたいと思います。
プロセスごとに異なるメモリ空間となるため、それぞれの子プロセス内で、setLoggerを同じ設定で行う必要があります。
以下にサンプルコードを記述します。

起動させると特に問題なくログが記述され、ファイルもローテーションされます。

このような使用方法で正しいのでしょうか？

```py
import os
import time
import pathlib

import logging
import logging.handlers

from queue import Empty
from multiprocessing import Process, Queue
from multiprocessing import freeze_support,set_start_method

def setLogger(log_name:str,path:str,level:str,file_size:int,file_count:int):

    logging.basicConfig(format='%(asctime)s %(threadName)s %(levelname)s:%(message)s')
    formatter = logging.Formatter('%(asctime)s %(threadName)s %(levelname)s:%(message)s')

    ret_path = os.path.split(path)
    ret = pathlib.Path(ret_path[0]).mkdir(parents=True,
                                        exist_ok=True)

    hLog =logging.handlers.RotatingFileHandler(path,'a',maxBytes=file_size,backupCount=file_count)
    hLog.setFormatter(formatter)
    logger = logging.getLogger(log_name)
    logger.setLevel(level)
    logger.addHandler(hLog)

    return logger

class SubProcess():
    def run(self,Name,log_name:str,path:str,level:str,file_size:int,file_count:int):
        alog = setLogger(
            log_name = log_name,
            path = path,
            level = level,
            file_size = file_size,
            file_count = file_count,
        )

        s = [Name for _ in range(1000)]
        s = ''.join(s)

        while(True):
            time.sleep(0.1)

            alog.info('{}:{}'.format(Name,s))


if __name__ == '__main__':
    freeze_support()
    set_start_method('spawn')

    log_size = 1*1024*1024
    log_files = 2
    log_name = 'app'
    log_level = 'INFO'

    current_path = os.getcwd()
    log_path_app = current_path + '\\log\\applog.log'

    alog = setLogger(
        log_name = log_name,
        path = log_path_app,
        level = log_level,
        file_size = log_size,
        file_count = log_files,
    )

    instSub1 = SubProcess()

    instSub1Pro = Process(
        target=instSub1.run,
        args =('Sub1',log_name,log_path_app,log_level,log_size,log_files),
        )
    instSub1Pro.start()

    instSub2 = SubProcess()

    instSub2Pro = Process(
        target=instSub2.run,
        args =('Sub2',log_name,log_path_app,log_level,log_size,log_files),
        )
    instSub2Pro.start()

    s = ['####' for _ in range(1000)]
    s = ''.join(s)

    while(True):
        time.sleep(0.1)

        alog.info('MainProcess:{}'.format(s))
```

Comment: 公式のドキュメントにこんなのがあります。[複数のプロセスからの単一ファイルへのログ記録 - Logging クックブック](https://docs.python.org/ja/3/howto/logging-cookbook.html#logging-to-a-single-file-from-multiple-processes)

Comment: ありがとうございます。これですね。